# FacebookSDK 4.x Crash Case

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I use FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.28.0 and [developer facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) suggest this lines of code to sharing;

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.lcwaikiki.com"];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

However when code comes to `[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];` code line application CRASH with SIGABRT

Anyone has any information to solve above mentioned CRASH case?

Thanks All.

Comment: Can you add your crash logs

Comment: Thanks @Himanth i found solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution about above mentioned CRASH problem.

If your iOS application base SDK<=iOS9, you must add "*fbauth2*","*fbapi*" etc. under the *LSApplicationQueriesSchemes* into .*plist* file.

You can deep into [Facebook SDK iOS9 guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9/)